# Caching - IDictionary vs top level key prefixes

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, dictionary

When storing a dictionary for fast lookup into the cache, i could think of two options:
Either storing a whole dictionary as a cache item, or prefixing cache keys with the identifiers.

Example:

```
myPseudoCache.Put("Users", myDictionaryWithGuidsAsKeys);
```

vs

```
myPseudoCache.Put("Users_" + userId, singleUserEntity);
```

The environment is C# with the HttpRuntime.Cache in an ASP.NET application, if that is of any interest, but I am also interested in general Thoughts (Maintainability aspects, performance, etc).

I am trying to make a reasonable decision here, but really am not sure about concrete advantages and disadvantages. Maybe someone with more experience could give me some advice on what to consider? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The second one will make it very hard to do something `foreach` cached item, if that's a concern.

Comment: thanks @Rawling, definitely something important. Although i do not need to iterate the objects right now, i might very well need to do it sometime. thanks again for that aspect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually a trade-off. If myPseudoCache is going to contain only 'Users', you could go with the second approach - i.e. `myPseudoCache.Put("Users_" + userId, singleUserEntity);`

If there are many disparate items (say Groups, Roles), especially with different frequencies, an exploded cache structure may not be the most optimum one. In this case, it makes sense to follow a tree-like structure or a dictionary within a dictionary - i.e.`myPseudoCache.Put("Users", myDictionaryWithGuidsAsKeys);`

For example; If your number of roles are less, a role lookup need not suffer because of an extraordinarily high number of users.

Comment: I see, in my case the cache will not only be storing one sort of objects. Your answer together with @Rawling's comment already makes me want to store a dictionary. thanks!

Comment: thanks, with the edit your answer totally satisfies my concerns. I will go for the tree-like approach, thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I think better option is to keep whole dictionary than separated values. First of all it's much more easier to iterate between keys in Dictionary. For me there is no difference in capacity. So the biggest profit is that this option is easier to mantain and the code would be clearer epecially when you will get the data from cache.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i totally agree with you now. To me, it just seems like the correct, natural way to do it after these answers :)